# python xpath how to add special characters in my xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, special-characters

this is the id that i want to extract

```
\"ctl00_ctl69_g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873_grdViewUnit\"
```

i tried this xpath in python (scrapy)

```
table = sel.xpath(".//table[@id='\"ctl00_ctl69_g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873_grdViewUnit\"']//tr")
```

it is absolutely wrong, how can i do a correct insert for these quotes and slashes and backslashes

if you can give me also an official website for that please, appreciate it

[image]

my code after the answer is :

```
table = sel.xpath(".//table[contains(@id, 'grdViewUnit')]//tr")
        for one in table:
             Region = one.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
             Area=one.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract()[0]
             Description=one.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract()[0]
             TotalWorth=one.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract()[0]
             print(Region+Area+Description+TotalWorth)
```

but it is not working, i dont know if the wrong is from my code or from my xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the backslash:

```
//table[@id = '\\"ctl00_ctl69_g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873_grdViewUnit\\"']//tr
```

Or, you can use a *partial match*:

```
//table[contains(@id, 'ctl00_ctl69_g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873_grdViewUnit')]//tr
```

Comment: but actually you removed the `\"` from the begining and from the end of my id, why pleaes? is it because of the contain stuff?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli well, are you actually sure `\"` parts are actually parts of an id?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli got it, thanks, updated the answer. Lmk if it helps.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, i updated my question again containing my code, i don't know if the wrong from my code or from my xpath can you check please? it seems not every table has the `grdViewUnit` but nevertheless, i would like to add the whole id